# Binding to collections of ViewModels or business models?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, mvvm, listbox

please help me understand MVVM better:

I had been binding listboxes to lists of custom objects, but then I ran into some trouble with having selected items populate / bind correctly in a multi select list.

The solution I found used a List just for that list box, (or at least that's what I understood) and then the viewmodel class could have an IsSelected property, which worked for me.

My questions are this:  Is this common to bind a listbox to a list of view models? it seems so strange, and if ti's normal, is binding a list box to a list of business objects bad MVVM technique?

Finally, when I bind a listbox to this list of viewmodels, how typically are those linked back to the list of business objects that they represent? do I keep an id in the view model, or a reference to the business object itself?  Sorry for these questions, but I am trying to learn MVVM and do it right.

here is the viewmodel I am putting in a list and binding to the listbox:

```
class ItemViewModel
{
    public ItemViewModel(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { 
            return isSelected; 
        }
        set { 
            isSelected = value; 
        }
    }
}
```

here is the xaml for the listbox in the view

```
<ListBox Height="401" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Users}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource listBoxTemplate}" SelectionMode="Multiple"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="202,29,0,0" Name="lbxAuthorizedUsers" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="154" >
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>`
```

and here is the Users property in the view model

```
public List<ItemViewModel> Users
{
    get { return this.users; }
    set { this.users = value; }
}
```

Comment: WPF, Silverlight or WP7?

Comment: WPF, added it as a tag, didn't think it mattered.

Comment: I don't think it matters either; I was only asking out of curiosity :)

Comment: if the Users List can change during runtime, then use an ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>. And if the ItemViewModels properties can change then implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
besides from that your code looks fine on first glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have seems fine

The idea behind the MVVM design pattern is to keep your UI layer separate from the business logic layer. An ideal MVVM application can run with any UI (or no UI at all), so if you have some kind of business logic based off Selected Users, then you should either have a `SelectedUsers` collection on your ViewModel, or an `IsSelected` property on your User object.

As a side note, if you want WPF to automatically update it's UI when a property in your ViewModels or Models change, make sure they implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx). And if you want them to automatically update when a collection changes, make sure to use an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) instead of a `List`

I started learning MVVM with [this article by Josh Smith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), which is a great introduction to the design pattern although when I was first starting out I had a hard time understanding it. If you're looking for something simpler, you can check out the [simple MVVM example](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/) I wrote

Comment: thanks that helps! I decided to have a reference to the object inside the View Model (which I made a generic)

Answer (score 1):

Also, your ViewModel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged so that it can notify the View of any changes.